# Extract multiple matching substrings from a string using bash script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I wanted to parse UI Test logs to extract the average duration of individual tests which are signified by `OS Signpost Duration`. I have been able to extract lines that contain `OS Signpost Duration` from multiple log files.

```
/Users/username/Projects/uitest/uitestUITests/uitestUITests.swift:44: Test Case '-[uitestUITests.uitestUITests test2]' measured [OS Signpost Duration (test 2 tapped), s] average: 4.001, relative standard deviation: 0.017%, values: [4.001285, 4.000268, 4.002284, 4.000665, 4.001234], performanceMetricID:com.apple.dt.XCTMetric_OSSignpost-test 2 tapped.duration, baselineName: "", baselineAverage: , maxPercentRegression: 10.000%, maxPercentRelativeStandardDeviation: 10.000%, maxRegression: 0.000, maxStandardDeviation: 0.000 /Users/username/Projects/uitest/uitestUITests/uitestUITests.swift:33: Test Case '-[uitestUITests.uitestUITests testExample]' measured [OS Signpost Duration (test 1 tapped), s] average: 2.001, relative standard deviation: 0.017%, values: [2.001135, 2.001209, 2.000610, 2.000730, 2.000262], performanceMetricID:com.apple.dt.XCTMetric_OSSignpost-test 1 tapped.duration, baselineName: "", baselineAverage: , maxPercentRegression: 10.000%, maxPercentRelativeStandardDeviation: 10.000%, maxRegression: 0.000, maxStandardDeviation: 0.000 /Users/username/Projects/uitest/uitestUITests/uitestUITests.swift:54: Test Case '-[uitestUITests.uitestUITests testLaunchPerformance]' measured [OS Signpost Duration (AppLaunch), s] average: 0.463, relative standard deviation: 12.413%, values: [0.539167, 0.385542, 0.463822, 0.512382, 0.415148], performanceMetricID:com.apple.dt.XCTMetric_OSSignpost-AppLaunch.duration, baselineName: "", baselineAverage: , maxPercentRegression: 10.000%, maxPercentRelativeStandardDeviation: 10.000%, maxRegression: 0.000, maxStandardDeviation: 0.000 /Users/username/Projects/uitest/uitestUITests/uitestUITests.swift:44: Test Case '-[uitestUITests.uitestUITests test2]' measured [OS Signpost Duration (test 2 tapped), s] average: 4.001, relative standard deviation: 0.018%, values: [4.000617, 4.000975, 4.002513, 4.000692, 4.001549], performanceMetricID:com.apple.dt.XCTMetric_OSSignpost-test 2 tapped.duration, baselineName: "", baselineAverage: , maxPercentRegression: 10.000%, maxPercentRelativeStandardDeviation: 10.000%, maxRegression: 0.000, maxStandardDeviation: 0.000 /Users/username/Projects/uitest/uitestUITests/uitestUITests.swift:33: Test Case '-[uitestUITests.uitestUITests testExample]' measured [OS Signpost Duration (test 1 tapped), s] average: 2.001, relative standard deviation: 0.020%, values: [2.000350, 2.001232, 2.000362, 2.001022, 2.000259], performanceMetricID:com.apple.dt.XCTMetric_OSSignpost-test 1 tapped.duration, baselineName: "", baselineAverage: , maxPercentRegression: 10.000%, maxPercentRelativeStandardDeviation: 10.000%, maxRegression: 0.000, maxStandardDeviation: 0.000 /Users/username/Projects/uitest/uitestUITests/uitestUITests.swift:54: Test Case '-[uitestUITests.uitestUITests testLaunchPerformance]' measured [OS Signpost Duration (AppLaunch), s] average: 0.416, relative standard deviation: 15.702%, values: [0.495147, 0.413174, 0.378256, 0.478277, 0.317015], performanceMetricID:com.apple.dt.XCTMetric_OSSignpost-AppLaunch.duration, baselineName: "", baselineAverage: , maxPercentRegression: 10.000%, maxPercentRelativeStandardDeviation: 10.000%, maxRegression: 0.000, maxStandardDeviation: 0.000 /Users/username/Projects/uitest/uitestUITests/uitestUITests.swift:44: Test Case '-[uitestUITests.uitestUITests test2]' measured [OS Signpost Duration (test 2 tapped), s] average: 4.002, relative standard deviation: 0.010%, values: [4.002300, 4.001725, 4.001849, 4.001945, 4.001093], performanceMetricID:com.apple.dt.XCTMetric_OSSignpost-test 2 tapped.duration, baselineName: "", baselineAverage: , maxPercentRegression: 10.000%, maxPercentRelativeStandardDeviation: 10.000%, maxRegression: 0.000, maxStandardDeviation: 0.000 /Users/username/Projects/uitest/uitestUITests/uitestUITests.swift:33: Test Case '-[uitestUITests.uitestUITests testExample]' measured [OS Signpost Duration (test 1 tapped), s] average: 2.000, relative standard deviation: 0.020%, values: [2.001171, 2.000079, 2.000173, 2.000237, 2.000132], performanceMetricID:com.apple.dt.XCTMetric_OSSignpost-test 1 tapped.duration, baselineName: "", baselineAverage: , maxPercentRegression: 10.000%, maxPercentRelativeStandardDeviation: 10.000%, maxRegression: 0.000, maxStandardDeviation: 0.000 /Users/username/Projects/uitest/uitestUITests/uitestUITests.swift:54: Test Case '-[uitestUITests.uitestUITests testLaunchPerformance]' measured [OS Signpost Duration (AppLaunch), s] average: 0.598, relative standard deviation: 31.034%, values: [0.888853, 0.613004, 0.690106, 0.402929, 0.395714], performanceMetricID:com.apple.dt.XCTMetric_OSSignpost-AppLaunch.duration, baselineName: "", baselineAverage: , maxPercentRegression: 10.000%, maxPercentRelativeStandardDeviation: 10.000%, maxRegression: 0.000, maxStandardDeviation: 0.000
```

The result is a combined text of multiple matching lines.
Now, if you notice in the above text, you can see data like

1. [OS Signpost Duration (test 2 tapped), s] average: 4.001
2. [OS Signpost Duration (test 1 tapped), s] average: 2.001
3. [OS Signpost Duration (AppLaunch), s] average: 0.463

Now what I wanted to do is, extract something to iterate over like a dictionary (or hashmap) (ignoring the duplicates)

```
[
 "test 2 tapped": 4.001,
 "test 1 tapped": 2.001,
 "AppLaunch"    : 0.463
]
```

I want to extract like this so that I can iterate over a variable and send this data to an API.
Any help would be appreciated 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to create a little script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

FILE_PATH='/tmp/tmp'

parsed_data=`\
    sed -e 's/\(\/[^:/]*\)*:[0-9]*:/\n/g' $FILE_PATH | \
    sed -e 's/^.*Duration (\(.*\)).*average: \([0-9.]\+\).*$/\2 \1/g' -e '/^$/d'
`

while read avg name; do
    printf "name: $name\tavg: $avg\n"
done <<< $parsed_data
```

#### Explanation

The 1st `sed` is only there to split the input in lines, to have only 1 result per line:
* **`\(\/[^:/]*\)*`** ➤ This captures a **path** (e.g. "/User/My/Path/foo.sh"):
    + **`\/`** is a single slash (e.g. `/`)
    + **`[^:/]*`** is anything that doesn't contain a slash or a colon (e.g. `User`)
    + **`\(...\)*`** is used to capture the group and repeat as many time as possible
* **`:[0-9]*:`** ➤ This matches the line numbers, present after the path (e.g. ":44:")
* **`\n`** ➤ And then we **replace** all of that by a newline

So in the end, this splits the input at each file names

The additionnal operation (**`/^$/d`**) is used to delete empty lines

---

The **2nd `sed`** isolates the parts that we're interested in:

- **`^.*Duration`**  ➤ Anything from the beginning of the line up to "Duration"
- **`(\(.*\))`**     ➤ Any string contained within parenthesis (**this is our title**). Note that we **capture** the pattern (using escaped braces - `\(...\)`)
- **`.*average:`**   ➤ Everything up to "average:"
- **`\([0-9.]\+\)`** ➤ Any number (`[0-9]`) or dot (`.`). Note that we also capture this part: this is our average.
- **`.*$`**          ➤ Everything up to the end of the line

---

So at this point, we matched the whole line, and we **captured** the title and average.

---

Now we just need to replace all of that by the captured group:
- `\2 \1` ➤ This represents the number (`\2`), and the title (`\1`).

We put the average first so that it's easier to read (because the title might have multiple words...)

So at this point, we have a string that looks like so:

```
12.2345 My small title
15.2345 My loong long title
62.2345 My title
```

Then we just need to call read on each line:

```
read avg name
```

The `read` here stores the 1st word (so the average) in the `avg` variable, and the remaining part (the title) in the `name` variable